# OpenVPN and AWS VPC. VPN Client can connect to VPN and ping VPN Server but cannot connect to VPC Servers through the VPN

Tags: amazon-web-services, openvpn, amazon-vpc

I'm having issues routing traffic from the VPN Clients to the LAN the openvpn server is on.

This is running in AWS VPC. I can ping vpn client and server from one another, but not the other servers in the vpc from the client.  My vpn lan is the default 10.8.0.0/24 and the VPC lan is 10.0.0.0/24. I have enabled ip forwarding.
I'm using a setup similar to the second one here https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/BridgingAndRouting and I've setup those iptables rules on the server. I added a route in the AWS Routes for the VPC subnet to point the VPN subnet to the VPC ip of the openvpn server. I have the windows firewall completely off. I want to be able to connect to servers in the VPC lan from the clients, but so far pings, ssh, rdp are all failing. I am running OpenVPN 2.3.2 on Ubuntu 14.04 and Openvpn Gui for windows 10.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

my server config, client config and openvpn server iptables https://gist.github.com/greyhammer/7eba7bf3e9e3bf2e3b0f

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was missing a NAT Command.

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Then don't forget to save the Iptables to make sure its still set after reboot