# Set up a VPN inside my VPC. Why can I not connect to other hosts on the VPC?

Tags: vpn, amazon-web-services, openvpn, amazon-vpc

Note: there is a similar quiestion [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/741904/openvpn-and-aws-vpc-vpn-client-can-connect-to-vpn-and-ping-vpn-server-but-canno), but I do not understand the answer.

I have just set up a VPN server using OpenVPN on an EC2 host inside my VPC. I've configured the VPN to tunnel all of my internet traffic through the VPN. I've connected to the VPN successfully and it does appear to be working (my public IP has changed). The issue is that I cannot connect to any other hosts in the VPC. If I edit my security groups to explicitly whitelist my IP, then I can connect, but that was not the intention of setting up the VPN.

What set am I missing?

Comment: Did you configure the VPC routing table correctly so that hosts in the VPC can route traffic properly to your private VPN IP address(es)?

Comment: I didn't modify the routing table, so probably not. I'm unsure what the correct value should be. I am definitely under qualified to do networking work.

Comment: Read through some VPC/OpenVPN tutorials. They'll no doubt cover what needs to be done.

Comment: I've already read some guides. I don't really understand the problem and that makes it hard to find a solution.

Comment: I'd recommend reading on some basic TCP/IP networking stuff then. Concepts you'll learn are applicable inside VPC and elsewhere.

Comment: Could you provide some references?

Comment: *If I edit my security groups to explicitly whitelist my IP, then I can connect, but that was not the intention* ... do you mean your private IP assigned on the VPN, or just which IP?  Why would you expect to be exempt from security group configuration because you're tunneling in via a VPN? (Please explain.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I edit my security groups to explicitly whitelist my IP, then I can connect,

I am more than absolutely sure that the reason for the issue is your security group configuration. If the problem was in your routes, changing security groups haven't made any difference.

> but that was not the intention of setting up the VPN.

Security group is acting like a firewall. If you want to connect to an instance, you need to allow connection via a specified port from a specified resourse. Otherwise, everything that behind your firewall will not be available. So the only solution is to add your IP to the security group exlusion.

Primary goal of a VPN in AWS is to access instances that are located in private subnets (in other words, not available via public internet) from your on-premises. An example is described here:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Scenario4.html

Comment: Thanks. I needed to configure my security groups to talk to each other. I had one security group for the VPN and one for my other hosts. You can add rules to allow all traffic between security groups via the console or API. Thanks!